Can you see through a cannonball packing?
More precisely, in a regular sphere packing, either the
HCP or FCC lattice packing,
does there exist a line $L$ disjoint from every sphere,
i.e., not touching any sphere?
If so, one could "look through" the packing along the line-of-sight $L$.

Image from a (much!) earlier posting:


Originally posted on MSE, but garnered no interest over a week.

What if the cannonballs are reflective? Is there a ray starting in one face of the pyramid and ending in another?

@Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda: That was the suggestion that led to that 14 year-old Christmas-tree posting. The answer there does not resolve your more fundamental question.

Yes. View the FCC packing as a series of stacked square packings, with spheres of unit radii centered at the points $(2a,2b,2\sqrt{2}c)$ and $(2a+1,2b+1,(2c+1)\sqrt{2})$ for all $a,b,c,\in\mathbb Z$:
                                   
Then we can take the line $\{(x,1,0.01)\ |\ x\in\mathbb R\}$, which lies just above the contact points of spheres in the $z=0$ layer but isn't high enough on the $z$-axis to risk contacting any other layer.
Here's a diagram of the "holes" one can see through when viewing the packing along the $x$ axis:


Is this the same packing? This looks on the picture as square-grid based, while the original question was about triangle-grid based.

@domotorp: It is, but viewed from a different direction.

@domotorp: It might help to look at the two cuboctahedron images on the Wikipedia page to see how the square grid and the triangular grid are actually the same packing.

Very nice! Am I correct that the same argument does not hold for the HCP packing?

@JosephO'Rourke this argument only considers two adjacent layers of the packing, right? If so then it applies equally to FCC and HCP.

To add to @SamHopkins' observation, in the HCP case there's another kind of hole as well: looking "down" into the hexagonal layers of an ABABAB... packing, the "C" type holes are never covered and also provide lines of sight.

@SamHopkins: I'm not sure about that - FCC can be viewed as a series of square packings, but I don't think that applies to HCP.

@user2357112: It's true that HCP doesn't have entire planar slices that form square packings, but it does have two parallel "lines" of spheres that meet at squares, and whose next layer up meets in the same way as in the FCC packing, and that's enough for the argument to go through.

I suspect a similar construction will work for every known lattice packing in dimension greater than $3$. If we take a lattice packing of spheres of radius $r$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and consider a vector $v$ in the lattice of length $2r$ (so that the corresponding pair of spheres is touching), the projection of the lattice to the orthogonal complement of $v$ will have a density equal to the density of the original packing times the volume of an $n-1$-dimensional sphere of radius $r$ times $2r$ divided by the volume of an $n$-dimensional sphere of radius $r$.

Up to an (approximately) constant factor, this is the density of the original packing times $\sqrt{n}$. As long as the density of the original packing is less than $1$ over a constant times $\sqrt{n}$, the projection will have density  less than $1$ and hence can't be a covering. But the known sphere packings have densities that are exponentially small in $n$, so the projection will not be a covering (i.e. you can see through) for large $n$. But since it happens for the best known packings for $n=3$ the "large n" probably starts already at $n=3$.
